# Why can't inequalities with logarithms be calculated correctly?

Tags: equation-solving

```
In[474]:= Solve[{Log[p1/p0] >= Log[p2/p0], p0 > 0, 60 <= p1 <= 90, 
  50 <= p2 <= 60, t == p1/p2}, t, {p0, p1, p2}]

During evaluation of In[474]:= Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

Out[474]= Solve[{Log[p1/p0] >= Log[p2/p0], p0 > 0, 60 <= p1 <= 90, 
  50 <= p2 <= 60, t == p1/p2}, t, {p0, p1, p2}]
```

```
In[475]:= Reduce[{Log[p1/p0] >= Log[p2/p0], p0 > 0, 60 <= p1 <= 90, 
  50 <= p2 <= 60, t == p1/p2}, t, {p0, p1, p2}]

During evaluation of In[475]:= Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

Out[475]= Reduce[{Log[p1/p0] >= Log[p2/p0], p0 > 0, 60 <= p1 <= 90, 
  50 <= p2 <= 60, t == p1/p2}, t, {p0, p1, p2}]
```

the key to this:  t>=1

Comment: `sol = Reduce[{Log[p1/p0] >= Log[p2/p0], p0 > 0, 60 <= p1 <= 90, 
    50 <= p2 <= 60, t == p1/p2}, t, {p0, p1, p2}, Reals];
sol // Simplify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the original problem into two steps to clarify it.

```
sol=Reduce[{Log[p1/p0] >= Log[p2/p0], p0 > 0, 60 <= p1 <= 90, 
  50 <= p2 <= 60}, {p0, p1, p2}, Reals]
```

> `p0 > 0 && 60 <= p1 <= 90 && 50 <= p2 <= 60`.

`60 <= p1 <= 90 && 50 <= p2 <= 60` just a rectangle. We can easy to get the range of `t=p1/p2`.

```
Reduce[{t == p1/p2, sol}, t, {p0, p1, p2}, Reals] // Simplify
```

> `1 <= t <= 9/5`.